# How to find out size occupied by data table/data set in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-management, datatable, size

I am confused about size occupied by data table or data set. When a data table object is created then what is the size of that object and how it increases the size as required. Suppose a there is table with 10 rows in database having 5 columns and this table will make the data table then what will be its size in memory. I am just confused about all this things. I did some googling but did not get any answer. How can I find size of data table/data set at any particular moment.